# Get items from "Windows Task Manager" process list c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pinvoke, listviewitem

I'm trying to get all the items from "Windows Task Manager" process list and add them to a listbox in my application. I have found code to get the handle of the process list on task manger. And I have code to delete an item from the list using its index (Its a good way to test that I have the right handle). But I need c# code to get the total number of items in the process list and to get items by there indexes. Ill settle for simply getting all the items in order and adding them to my listbox.

Edit: Thank you for your comments, I'll explain more...
I'm not trying to just list the processes, Otherwise I would use: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
I want to get the processes sorted in the way which they are sorted in task manger.
Task manger has many ways of sorting its processes. It provides about 31 different ways to do it. For example: Image Name, PID, Username, CPU usage ect. My objective is to get the processes in the order which they are sorted in Task Manger.

```
    static Int32 LVM_FIRST = 4096;
    static Int32 LVM_DELETEITEM = (LVM_FIRST + 8);
    static Int32 LVM_SORTITEMS = (LVM_FIRST + 48);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowA")]
    private static extern Int32 apiFindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowExA")]
    private static extern Int32 apiFindWindowEx(Int32 hWnd1, Int32 hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
    private static extern Int32 apiSendMessage(Int32 hWnd, Int32 wMsg, Int32 wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDesktopWindow")]
    private static extern Int32 apiGetDesktopWindow();


    void GetItems()
    {
        Int32 lhWndParent = apiFindWindow(null, "Windows Task Manager");
        Int32 lhWndProcessList = 0;
        Int32 lhWndDialog = 0;

        for (int i = 1; (i <= 7); i++)
        {
            // Loop through all seven child windows, for handle to the listview
            lhWndDialog = apiFindWindowEx(lhWndParent, lhWndDialog, null, null);
            if ((lhWndProcessList == 0))
            {
                lhWndProcessList = apiFindWindowEx(lhWndDialog, 0, "SysListView32", "Processes");
            }
        }


        /* This code removes the first item in the Task Manager Processes list:
         * apiSendMessage(lhWndProcessList, LVM_DELETEITEM, 0, "0");
         * note that the 3rd paramiter: 0, is the index of the item to delete.
         * I put it here in comments because I thought there would be
         * something similar to get the name*/

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        int TotalItemCount = /*Total item count in Task Manager Processes list*/;
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalItemCount; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(/*Get item  in Task Manager Processes list by index: i*/)

        }

    }
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel?  And your code going to fail when `TaskManager` is not opened. Use `Process.GetProcesses()`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the above approach will likely break with different versions of the operating system.

Comment: This is far harder than you think. You'll need to allocate memory in the process that owns the task manager window. You'll need ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory. Look for a different solution. Perhaps using the automation API would work.

Comment: @davidheff Thank you, That was the type of answer I was looking for. :) Now I know where to look.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the commenters don't reinvent the wheel. You can get the processes and sort like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

var sorted = myProcs.OrderBy(p => p.UserProcessorTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding user2838881 wants to get the way the processes in windows 7 are 
sorted on a windows machine. There are a number of ways when the task manager is running
that the processes are sorted. Due to this fact in order to use the code suggested as an answer he must find a way to sort the processes in task-manager through programming.
A way to accomplish that is the following line of code that can be added on his code before removing the process.

```
        apiSendMessage(lhWndProcessList,LVM_SORTITEMS,0,"0")
```